# Can my Android phone run Ubuntu Phone OS

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I recently heard that Android phones can be converted to Ubuntu phones... I just want to know if my phone Sony Xperia Sola(1GHz Dual-core, 512MB RAM) can run Ubuntu on it (is there really any provision for this)?

Please let me know, because I really want to get rid of my Android.